# Is it possible to get a null hypothesis from this? If so, what would it be?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I have been working on this for the past 4 hours.. sadly. I need to get the null and alternative hypothesis from an article that states a p value, and I chose this one.

http://eds.b.ebscohost.com/eds/pdfviewer/pdfviewer?sid=b537533e-4934-4987-acf8-b9e1e3e12d34%40sessionmgr113&vid=1&hid=104

Volume 39, Number 2, March-April 2015, American Journal of Health behavior, "Subjective Social Status and Readiness to Quit among Homeless Smokers."

It seems that the hypothesis (the one of many I chose) is "Higher SSS Community rankings will relate to greater readiness to quit." However, I am not sure how I could convert that to a null/alt hypothesis seeing as I don't know what numbers for me to set a mean equal to. The paper contains a lot but in my attempt to summarize, it attempts to show that a higher SSS rating (perception of your own status in the social hierarchy) among homeless people is linked to a higher readiness to smoke.

To simplify, how to I get both hypotheses (null/alt) in an article such as the listed when it isn't layed out in a nice question format such as what I am used to? What is the null and alternative in this situation?

What I understand so far and seem to be the information necessary to know is this:

The readiness to quit smoking at the lowest SSS Community (1) is -.03 and for the highest SSS Community (9) is .32, so the hypothesis is true since more are ready to quit if the SSS is higher. The probability is is "p < .001"

My problem is, I don't know how to put it into the format I was taught, which is Ho: (Mu) = x
I am not sure how to take the information I have and get the two hypotheses.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Also, please paste into the body of your question whatever context is necessary to understand it. Eg, provide a complete citation for the paper (in case the link goes dead), & paste quoted text from the paper (perhaps w/ terms defined or whatever is necessary).

Comment: The "format you were taught" seems to be for a very specific kind of test, where you're comparing a mean to a prespecified value (likely a one-sample t-test). There are dozens of other tests in common use. The paper looks like it's testing whether a correlation is zero (or not zero under the alternative), which is similar to what you're familiar with, but somewhat different.

Answer (score 0):

The notation for a null hypothesis that you have listed seems to be for a one-sample t-test.  The description of the content of the paper (which I have not read) seems to be about a correlation.

Comment: So it isn't possible with this article? Most of the articles I have found were like this, as in it didn't lay them out as simply as what I've seen so far. And your question seems to imply that there is a way to do it, but not in that format? Is that right?

Comment: @TonyKay, the null hypotheses for different tests differs. So you have 1 type of null for a 1-sample t-test, a different type for a 2-sample t-test, the null for a correlation is different again, etc. I don't see a problem w/ using this paper unless your assignment specifies a 1-sample t-test.

Comment: It doesn't specify, so I guess I would need to calculate the null for both cases and compare them? That somewhat makes sense. So say I took the lowest level (1). And, then I would do: Ho: Mu = -.03, right? If that't the case, then would would I try to do for alt? Alt is where I would compare right?

Comment: I wouldn't try to come up with a bunch of 1-sample t-test nulls. If what they did was something ultimately related to a correlation, I would come up with a null for that. As for the alternative hypothesis, I would figure out the null 1st & then think about how the null & alternative have to relate logically.

Comment: @gung: sorry I deleted the comment